# Storing an X.509 certificate in a Java keystore

Tags: java, keystore, x509, rampart

I am trying to store a proxy X.509 certificate into a keystore. The certificate is generated using bouncycastle library, the problem is that I do not have the secret key for the certificate and from what I understand is that to store it in a Java key store I need the secret key. Furthermore I can't seem to convert the certificate into Java's own implementation of it.
I want to store it in a keystore so that Axis2's Rampart could attach it to SOAP messages according to our own security architecture.
IF anyone can kindly explain to me if there is a way to do this or if I am missing something important I would be thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from what I understand is that to store it in a Java key store I need the secret key

No. You don't need the private key to store a certificate. You only need that for your own certificate. Just use `keytool -import.`